# Is there shorter notation for this simple query?

Tags: mysql

I am building a query covering several WHERE AND conditions. Here is an example:

```
... 
WHERE stage1 = 3 
AND stage2 = 3 
AND stage3 = 3 
AND stage4 = 3 
AND stage5 = 3 
AND submitted = 0
```

Is there a shorter way of writing this, perhaps like `WHERE TRUE(stage1=3 & stage2=3 ...)` ?

Edit - just for info, here's the table:

[image]

Comment: Your suggested alternative just wraps the same problem in an extra thing!

Comment: I tested something like this: WHERE stage1 = 3 AND (stage1=stage2=stage3...) but doesn't work. SQL keeps amazing me.

Comment: @santiago: Why is that "amazing"? More amazing is that such a "requirement" came up at all.

Comment: @Tomalak haha, you're right. But i thought that should work, and it didn't. Maybe it's becouse of the weird SQL92 from MySQL.

Comment: Weird? I don't know of many languages that support `3=a=b=c` type of conditions. Python comes to mind but nothing else.

Comment: Indeed. It's highly unusual for that syntax to do what you expect. (Note: `a=b=c` in C-style languages is *not* the same; the equivalent here would be `a==b==c` which does not do what you think!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shorter way to write that would be:

```
WHERE (stage1, stage2, stage3, stage4, stage5, submitted)
    = (3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0)
```

It won't be any faster though, either way you write it.

Comment: +1 I didn't know of this notation, and it actually renders my answer false. But as you point out, it won't be faster, and it isn't any much clearer either.

Comment: No, and it's not going to work if you move to another RDBMS (which doesn't support it). But it's handy when you want to have a condition like `(a,b,c) <= (5,3,2)` (lexikographic ordering).

Comment: I like that. Would the following work... WHERE (stage1, stage2, stage3, stage4, stage5) = (3)

Comment: `WHERE stage5=3` would work though. If week5 is complete, the previous weeks should be too, shouldn't they? (really check again your table structure)

Comment: Interesting syntax, +1 for new one ;-)

Comment: @ ypercube - the form can be updated at any time over a period of weeks and validation is not performed until the whole form is submitted (except that non-empty fields are validated!). So a user does not have to move sequentially through the form parts.

Comment: Will this notation work in with other conditions: (stage1, stage2, stage3) = (in (1,2), in (0,1), !3)

Comment: @Owen Don't you think that `stage1 in (1,2) and stage2 in (0,1) and stage3 <> 3` looks bettter?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. And the notation you suggest is not really shorter. :)

Why would you need it to be shorter, and what table structure do you have where all these stage fields should be 3?

[edit] Added a solution for querying stages from a hypothetical detail table.

```
select
  *
from 
  FormsTable f
where
  f.submitted = 0 and
  not exists
    (select 'x' 
    from 
      PageDetailTable d
    where
      d.FormId = f.FormId and
      d.State <> 3)
```

This is hardly shorter at the moment, but when you get more complex form that consist of more (or less) pages, you can support this more easily. When you create a form, you create a record for each page it consists of. In the page record you can store not only the state, but also other data you may need. When you get a different type of form with more or less pages, you can just create those pages. This query just checks if the form is not submitted and if it doesn't have any pages that are not finished yet. It doesn't matter how many pages there are.

Comment: +1 for pointing the potential design flaw with multiple similar fields.

Comment: Well the design can no doubt be improved but that will be the subject of a different question. The table is a simple record of the status of a section of a multiple page form, the submission of which can be over a period of weeks so, status 1 - not started, 2 - underway, 3 - completed.

Comment: In that case it can certainly be improved. If you create a detail table for those pages, each with a state, you can add pages to the form without having to modify your table. In your current setup, you will need to add columns. And besides that, it isn't exactly clear which page belongs to 'stage1'. But that's the answer to a  different question indeed. :)

Comment: I couldn't help myself and add a query that would work if those page states would be in a separate table.

Comment: @GolezTrol - the pages stages are in a separate table, see edit.